Alignment of the currency symbol in a tabular environment
I'm typesetting a table of monetary sums in LaTeX. So far, I have the following code:
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{k}{>{\$\hfill\,}r} % currency columns

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lkk}
    \toprule
    \textsc{Description} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textsc{Suggested price}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\textsc{Price}}\\
    \midrule
    Item A      & 100,00   & 20,00\\
    Long item B & 1.000,00 & 2.000,00\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

which gets compiled into:

It's fine, but I would like it better if the dollar signs were left-aligned only as much as needed, considering only the entries after the heading, like so:

My questions are:

Can that be reasonably done?
Is there a better way to separate the "heading" formatting from that of the rest of the table? (In this case, I used a \multicolumn{1}... to keep the dollar signs from appearing in the header, but it feels very ad hoc)


Maybe have a look at the siunitx package. Or just remove the dollar signs and write into the header that the values are a currency.

@Mico I'll edit the post, thanks!

I endorse Mico's suggestions, with some improvements:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}

\sisetup{% <-- global settings
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  group-separator=.,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\sisetup{% <-- local settings
  group-minimum-digits=4,
  round-mode=places,
  round-precision=2,
}
\newcolumntype{k}[1]{% <-- local definition
  >{\$\ }% $ symbol in front
  S[table-format=\$\ #1.2]%
} % price columns

\begin{tabular}{@{} l k{4} k{4} @{}}
\toprule
\scshape Description & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\scshape Price} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\scshape Suggested}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\scshape Actual} \\
\midrule
Item A      &  100,00 &   20,00 \\
Long item B & 1000,00 & 2000,00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption for the table}

\end{table}

\end{document}

This separates global settings for siunitx (quite curious, as where US dollars are the currency the decimal separator and group separator are swapped) from local settings for the particular table. Similarly, globally defining a k column type doesn't seem so useful.

However, unless you have different currencies (unlikely as you're hardwiring \$ in the k column), it's much better to state that prices are in US dollars in the header.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}

\sisetup{% <-- global settings
  output-decimal-marker={,},
  group-separator=.,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\sisetup{% <-- local settings
  group-minimum-digits=4,
  round-mode=places,
  round-precision=2,
}
\newcolumntype{k}[1]{% <-- local definition
  S[table-format=#1.2]%
} % price columns

\begin{tabular}{@{} l k{4} k{4} @{}}
\toprule
\scshape Description & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textsc{Price} (\$)} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-3}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\scshape Suggested}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\scshape Actual} \\
\midrule
Item A      &  100,00 &   20,00 \\
Long item B & 1000,00 & 2000,00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Caption for the table}

\end{table}

\end{document}



+1 for suggesting to place the $ symbol in the shared header of columns 2 and 3.

I would like to suggest that you employ the machinery of the siunitx package and, in particular, its S column type. In the code below, observe that it's not necessary to input the thousands-separator and that ",00" will be inserted automatically if the input consists of an integer number of dollars. Note also that the k column type now takes an argument: the (maximum) number of digits of the integer part of the dollar amounts.
I would further like to suggest that you impose a bit more visual hierarchy on the material in the header row(s). In the code below, I've maintained your apparent preference for rendering the header material in small-caps. That said, I don't think it's all that useful to make this font face switch, i.e., the information contained in the table would be just as effectively displayed if you used the default type face (here: serif) instead of small-caps.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,},
         group-minimum-digits=4,
         group-separator={.}}   
% bespoke column type for currency amounts:
\newcolumntype{k}[1]{>{\$\ }S[table-format=#1.2,
                     table-space-text-pre={\$\ },
                     round-mode=places, round-precision=2]}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l k{4} k{5} @{}}
  \toprule
  \textsc{Description} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\textsc{Price}} \\
  \cmidrule(l){2-3}
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{Suggested}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{\textsc{Actual}} \\
  \midrule
  Item A      & 100  & 20    \\
  Long item B & 7050 & 21700 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


+1, where is documented table-format=#1.2 (observe #)? In documentation of recent package version I didn't find this :(

@Zarko It’s #1 that stands for the argument.

@egreg, thank you! Off course. I overlooked that it is part of newcommand definition. My bed ...

I marked @egreg's answer as the accepted, as it did (however slightly) improve over yours, and would be the most useful for other users. However, there's no questioning that the credit for the answer goes to you. How's StackExchange etiquette in this regard? Let me know if I should mark yours as the accepted one.

@impresso - Thanks for this comment (and your praise). You're doing fine; you should definitely feel free to accept the answer you find best addresses your typesetting needs.

Based on nice @Mico answer, but with use of the tabularray package:
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,
                siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,},
         group-minimum-digits=4,
         group-separator={.}
         }   

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} l *{2}{S[table-format={\$\ }4.2]} @{}},
             cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
             cell{1}{2} = {c=2}{},
             cell{3-Z}{2-3} = {preto={\$\ }},
             row{1-2} = {c, guard, font=\scshape}
             }
                
  \toprule
  \textsc{Description} 
            &   Price   &                   \\
  \midrule
            &   Suggested
                        &   Actual          \\
  \midrule
Item A      &   100,00  &    20,00          \\
Long item B & 1 000,00  & 2 000,00          \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{center}

\end{document}


However, in the case, that you prefer @egreg suggestion about placement currency symbol, than you only need to replace table preamble and the first row in table body in above MWE with:
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} l *{2}{S[table-format=4.2]} @{}},
             cell{1}{1} = {r=2}{},
             cell{1}{2} = {c=2}{},
             row{1-2} = {c, guard, font=\scshape}
             }            
  \toprule
  \textsc{Description} 
            &   Price (\$)   &               \\

In this case result is:


Congratulations for your deserved 300k!

@egreg, thank you very much!

+1. Let me also congratulate you on surpassing the 300k rep mark!

Incidentally, what would it take to let users enter an integer amount, say, "20", and the software then supply the ",00" part automatically, to output "20,00"? And, could \textsc{Description} be replaced with just Description?

@Mico, thank you very much!. A good point. Two reasons: 1. that  table content stay as much as OP write it (in this I wasn't completely successful, I didn't found a way how preserve OP's group separators -- here I was curious how (s)he would write for example a number for twelve millions); 2. that the column specification is a wee bit different from yours :-).
